# Subscription does not execute when assign to a component property

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I tried to setup a timeout function with rxjs observable inside a angular2 component

```
this._subscription = Observable.timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
            console.log('inside timeout')
        })
```

and unsubscribe it in other method. However the observable never executed
If i change to

```
let _subscription = Observable.timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
            console.log('inside timeout')
        })
```

It works fine. I also tried with

```
this._subscription=setTimeout(()=>{},1000)
```

same thing happened. I suspect it's the ngZone bug so I wrap the function inside

```
this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {})
```

but result is the same. Anyone encounter the same issue before? i am using angular 2.2.4

Comment: _and unsubscribe it in other method_ - show the full code. _same thing happened_ - what same thing?

Comment: observable never executed. it Only execute if you don't assign it to a subscription variable or assign it to a local scope subscrioption variable it works.

Comment: that's not true, as soon as you subscribe to an observable it gets executed, in your case in 1000 ms you should see the log message **unless** you unsubscribe before the 1000 ms pass

Comment: In theory yes.but that's what i got.  It sounds spooky. I will try to put it in a plunker

Comment: yeah, create a plunker

Comment: Is it possible your unsubscribe is being triggered within 1 second? Test it with `Observable.of('my item')`, should invoke the console log with both patterns. Also, could you please advise if _subscription is a defined property of the component?

Answer (score 1):

Subscribing to an observable should be done (in most cases) within `ngOnInit` method.

So now, if you want to unsubscribe from it, you might do it like that:

```
private onDestroy$ = new Subject<void>();
private stopObs$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit() {
  someObs$
    // stop the observable if the component is being destroyed
    .takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)
    // stop the component from another method if you want
    .takeUntil(this.stopObs$)
    .do(x => console.log(`A value has been received: ${x}`))
    .subscribe();
}

callThisMethodToStopListeningToObs() {
  this.stopObs$.next();
  this.stopObs$.complete();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.onDestroy$.next();
  this.onDestroy$.complete();
}
```

Here `someObs$` might be an `interval`, a `timer` or whatever observable :).

Comment: ya it's possible approach however seems a bit too complex for my problem. I can fix it with a local variable let subs=setTimeout(), instead of this.subs=setTimeout() but i just want to know why component property assignment breaks settimeout

Comment: I don't see how this addresses Fan's question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i have a clear subscription in onNgInit to clear subscription upon Component initialisation.

NgInit is run after component method in which the observable sits. So it cancels the subscription immediately after it's created. Now i removed the subscription reset, it works fine. What i learnt is your component method can be called by other component before NgInit hook happen